# Processing: scale and transform

Tags: scale, processing, translate

In my processing application I want to translate a shape and scale it.
The coordinate, scale, and translate-values are saved in objects.
In each cycle I use the same translate-value per object and a bigger scale-value.

The problem is the 'scale' is somehow cumulated with the 'translate'- the scale does not happen in the middle of the object...

How can I setup the objects so the scaling happens at their center?

```
    for (int i = 1; i < formen.size(); i++) {

        Form f = formen.get(i);

        pushMatrix();

        f.sx = f.sx * 2;
        f.sy = f.sy * 2;
        scale(f.sx, f.sy);
        translate(f.tx, f.ty);

        noStroke();


        createShape();
        beginShape();
        vertex(f.ax, f.ay);
        bezierVertex(f.ax + f.kabx, f.ay, f.bx, f.by - f.kaby, f.bx, f.by);
        bezierVertex(f.bx, f.by + f.kbcy, f.cx + f.kbcx, f.cy, f.cx, f.cy);
        bezierVertex(f.cx - f.kcdx, f.cy, f.dx, f.dy + f.kcdy, f.dx, f.dy);
        bezierVertex(f.dx, f.dy - f.kday, f.ax - f.kdax, f.ay, f.ax, f.ay);

        endShape();

        popMatrix();

        delay(5);
    }
```

Comment: try doing the translate first and then the scale

Comment: unfortunately I already tried but this did not solved the problem... the forms are still moving, instead of being at their place and scaling...

Comment: Can you post a full sketch that shows everything you're doing? Note that it should be an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), not your entire codebase.

Comment: how about translate(-f.x, -f.y); scale(2); translate(f.x, f.y); translate(f.tx,f.ty);

Comment: thank you very much- in meantime I solved the problem by using a PShape-Object (where I can use ... shapeMode(CENTER);
            s.scale(f.sx, f.sy);
            shape(s, f.tx, f.ty);...)